# Most occuring digit in an array of numbers

Tags: c++, beginner

I stumbled upon this exercise , and I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing this. It is written from high school level knowledge.

> Find the most occuring number of an array of numbers, with each number only counting one per number. For example in 2222 the 2 only counts ONCE. If you have 2 or more digits with the same amount of occurrences write out a random one. For example X[3] = {20; 21; 30}, either write out 0 or 2.

I could've used dynamic arrays, but that's not what I'm interested in here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct numbers
{
int number;
int howmany;
};

int main()
{
int X[20], Z[9], sizex, i, j, temp, howmany_found = 0, howmany_elem = 0, max = 0;
numbers Y[10];
bool found;

srand(time(NULL));

cout << "Array size: " ;
cin >> sizex;

for (i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
{
    cout << i + 1 << " element: " << " " ;
    cin >> X[i];
}

for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    Y[i].number = i;
}

for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < sizex; j++)
    {
    found = false;
    temp = X[j];

    while (found != true && temp >= 1)
    {
        if (temp % 10 == i)
        {
            found = true;
            howmany_found++;

        }
        temp /= 10;
    }
    }
    Y[i].howmany = howmany_found;
    howmany_found = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    if (Y[i].howmany > max)
        max = Y[i].howmany;

    if (Y[i].howmany > 0)
    cout << "(" << Y[i].number << "," << Y[i].howmany << ")" ;
}

for (i = 0; i <=9; i++)
{
    if (Y[i].howmany == max)
    {
        Z[howmany_elem] = Y[i].number;
        howmany_elem++;
    }
}

if (howmany_elem > 1)
{
int RandIndex = rand() % howmany_elem ;
cout << endl;
cout << Z[RandIndex] ;
}
else
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << Z[0] ;
}

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Although you're a beginner, you may want to look into `std::map` and have the key be the number (i.e., 0 through 9) and the value for each be the number of occurrences of the key in the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Outer loop unnecessary

If there are `N` numbers, each with `M` digits, your solution is using `10 * N * M` operations to compute the solution.  This is because for each digit (e.g. 0, 1, 2), you look at every digit in every number.  But you could make your solution 10 times faster by only looking at each digit once.  All you need to do is to track duplicate digits for each new number.

Here is how that would work:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    Y[i].number = i;
    Y[i].howmany = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
{
    int foundDigits = 0;

    for (int curNumber = X[i]; curNumber > 0; curNumber /= 10) {
        int digit = curNumber % 10;
        int bit   = 1 << digit;

        if ((foundDigits & bit) == 0) {
            foundDigits |= bit;
            Y[digit].howmany++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `foundDigits` is a bitmask which contains a 1 bit for each digit already seen in the current number.  This is what is used to track duplicate digits.  When a non-duplicate digit is seen, we can just increment the `Y[digit].howmany` array directly.

### struct numbers unnecessary

Actually, the `numbers` structure is unnecessary because `Y[i].number` is always equal to `i`.  So you can just have `Y` be an array of integers holding the count of each digit.  Wherever you currently use `Y[i].number`, just replace that with `i` instead.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <time.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> ```

Order your includes.  On small projects in may not matter as the number of includes are small.  As the project size grows, you'll find yourself with a long list of external resources and you want to ensure that you do not have any cascading dependencies.  Ordering also helps with readability as it is very easy for the reader to find whether an include already exists in a sorted list.  Typical ordering is usually done by source type (interface/user libs/3rd party trusted libs/stl) then name.

Use the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) version of [c](/questions/tagged/c) libraries.  Libraries like `<time.h>`, `<std***.h>`, and others, typically just dump all of the variables and functions in the global namespace.  This is a source of pollution and can cause issues related to name collisions and implicit conversion errors.  Avoid these issues by  using `<ctime>`, `<cstdint>`, etc....

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Again, polluting the global namespace.  You can avoid many common errors by not importing the entire standard namespace and just qualify your types/functions with `std::`.

> ```
> struct numbers
> {
>     int number;
>     int howmany;
> };
> ```

The naming doesn't feel right with this.  Your structure is supposed to represent the count of a digit, but this structure is telling me it takes any `number` and tells me `howmany`.  Just better naming helps (and bounds checking if you want to validation).

Storing every digit requires knowing both the value and the count.  Using sequential containers, we can disregard the value (represented as the container index/key) and simply have the container maintain the count.

> ```
> int X[20], Z[9], sizex, i, j, temp, howmany_found = 0, howmany_elem = 0, max = 0;
> numbers Y[10];
> bool found;
> ```

Declare variables as locally as possible.  Variables can be initialized with proper meaningful values and properties (such as `const`).

> ```
> srand(time(NULL));
> ```

If you are using any modern compiler that supports [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or later, you should be using [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) in place of `std::rand`.  It has been determined that [rand() is harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and should no longer be used in C++11.

> ```
> cout << "Array size: " ;
> cin >> sizex;
> ```

Validate input was read successfully.  Consider using `unsigned` or `std::size_t` for your size type.

> ```
> for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
> {
>     Y[i].number = i;
> }
> ```

Write smaller, testable functions.  Write larger functions composed of your smaller tested functions to ensure everything works as it should.

Prefer pre-increment (++i) over post-increment (i++).  While most compilers are really good at optimizing primitive increments when it is the only statement being processed, being explicit with your incrementing allows you to avoid unnecessary copies of non-primitive types/objects.  Post-increment has its purpose and should only be used when you want to use the copy of the previous state.

Avoid using magic numbers.  Numbers like `9` represent a maximum digit.  What if our maximum digit was in a different base?  Define constants with `constexpr` if you are using [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or later, or `const`.

> ```
> while (found != true && temp >= 1)
> ```

Use the truthiness of a value to avoid comparing directly to `true` and `false`.  Truthiness is the implicit conversion of a values existence.  The truthiness of a primitive type such as `bool`, `int`, `double`, `char` tests whether the value is set to its non-defaulted constructed value (zero).  Non-primitive types only have this truthiness property if they have a defined `operator bool()`.  Knowing about truthiness, you can instead test for `!found`.

> ```
> cout << endl;
> ```

Be aware of what `std::endl` actually does.  `std::cout << std::endl;` is the equivalent of writing `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush;`.  The `std::flush` writes out the stream.  Luckily this has a very minimal impact on unbuffered streams like `std::cout`.  When you work with file streams and other buffered type streams, excessive and unnecessary flushes can be detrimental.  Avoid using `std::endl`.  If you have to flush the stream, use `std::flush` explicitly.  If you want to have a newline, explicitly print one out using `'\n'`.

> ```
> return 0;
> ```

`main()` is a special function and the standard has various rules regarding `main()`.  One such rule ([C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), 3.6.1 point 5) is the implicit addition of `return 0` at the end of `main()`.

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return
>   statement, the eﬀect is that of executing return 0;

Just be aware that some coding guidelines utilize this and actually want you to allow for the implicit return of the success case.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of implementations of the c headers pollute the standard namespace anyway, I believe there's a defect report out there about this. It's still definitely a good idea to use the proper headers, just unfortunate that some implementations might exactly what you would want here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use boolean values directly, no need to compare them to `true` or `false`. For example you can write:

```
if (! found) {
```

Instead of:

> ```
> if (found != true) {
> ```

---

You don't need the `found` variable at all. Instead of initializing it to false, setting it to true when you found a digit so that the loop exits, you could exit the loop using a `break` statement.

---

Instead of `struct numbers`, you could use a simple array, where the indexes correspond to the digits, and the values correspond to the counts.

---

Delay operations until you really need them.
For example, there are many inputs for which you don't need to generate random numbers, so you don't need to initialize `srand` until later.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few things that could be improved with this.

## C++ and code quality

### Variables

```
int X[20], Z[9], sizex, i, j, temp, howmany_found = 0, howmany_elem = 0, max = 0;
numbers Y[10];
```

It's much clearer if you don't declare different types of variables on the same line, you have both arrays here and regular `int`s. Making it one type per line or even one variable per line will be more readable. Additionally names such as `X` `Z` and `Y` don't mean a whole lot on their own, either choose more descriptive names or comment what these are doing. Also you can move the array index variables into the for loop scope which is generally a good idea:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
{
    cout << i + 1 << " element: " << " " ;
    cin >> X[i];
}
```

### Bounds checking:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
{
    cout << i + 1 << " element: " << " " ;
    cin >> X[i];
}
```

If `sizex` is greater than the size of the `X` array you will have a problem here. You should always explicitly check user input.

## Algorithm

### improving the inner most loop

There is a loop where most of the cycles will be spent so I'm focusing on that:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < sizex; j++)
    {
        found = false;
        temp = X[j];

        while (found != true && temp >= 1)
        {
            if (temp % 10 == i)
            {
                found = true;
                howmany_found++;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }
    Y[i].howmany = howmany_found;
    howmany_found = 0;
}
```

First up you have this variable called `howmany_found` this is already in the struct you defined earlier and is hence not needed.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizex; j++)
    {
        found = false;
        temp = X[j];

        while (found != true && temp >= 1)
        {
            if (temp % 10 == i)
            {
                found = true;
                Y[i].howmany += 1;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have already got rid of an unnecessary temporary variable and the associated assignments.

Now the next thing I would do is to exchange the loops:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizex; j++)
{
    temp = X[j];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        found = false;
        while ( found != true && temp >= 1)
        {
            if (temp % 10 == i)
            {
                found = true;
                Y[i].howmany += 1;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Now `temp = X[j];` is only done once instead of up to 9 times. The compiler might optimize this but it might not. The big upside of doing something like this is that you get better cache utilization. The reason this matters is because fetching things from main memory is really slow compared to getting them out of the CPU cache. In this case you want to minimize the number of times you have to do a potentially expensive read from main memory. Instead of doing 10 reads of `X[j]` we are now only doing one and saving this to the temporary variable which should now fit a lot better in the main cache.

As per Janos' answer you can get rid of the structure for the numbers and just use array indexing to store how many of each number you got.

For example:

```
std::array<int, 10> how_many;
std::fill(how_many.begin(), how_many.end(), 0);
```

then use as:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizex; j++)
{
    temp = X[j];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        found = false;
        while ( !found && temp > 0)
        {
            if (temp % 10 == i)
            {
                found = true;
                how_many[i] += 1;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

This means you are using one less integer for each value you are keeping track of. Depending on the architecture taking the modulo can be quite expensive. Some platforms (such as some of the Atmel microcontroller chips) have no hardware support for the modulo operation which would make this code very slow. In any case we don't need to perform this operation repeatedly for each number we want to check, we only need to take the modulo once.

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizex; j++)
{
    temp = X[j];
    std::array<bool, 10> found_in_current_number;
    std::fill(found_in_current_number.begin(), found_in_current_number.end(), false);

    while ( temp > 0)
    {
        int current_digit = temp % 10;
        if (!found_in_current_number[current_digit])
        {
            found_in_current_number[current_digit] = true;
            how_many[i] += 1;
        }
        temp /= 10;
    }
}
```

The tradeoff is that it take a little more memory overall because of the array that checks if the bits have already been found.

Conceptually this is a fairly similar approach to the bit manipulations approach in JS1's answer except that I have used an array of bools here as opposed to bitmasks. If I were writing performance critical production code to do this I would benchmark the speed of both these approaches. I suspect JS1's bit manipulation idea is faster but I'm not 100% sure. But again if this were production code I would definitely profile the code and not just make a guess.

It's possible that there's some further improvements that could be made to the runtime of this code but they will likely come with extra complexity. For example you might want to split the processing up across multiple threads or machines if you wanted to exploit some parallelism on your hardware. Also you might be able to improve performance with some other data structures. But you really need to profile these to make sure you are actually improving the performance and if that performance gain is worth the extra complexity.